# How to use classes appropriately in this example?

Tags: c#

### 1. Add an entry to the book.

Command syntax: add firstName lastName month day year Each entry in the birthday book consists of a first name, a last name, and a date. A date consists of a month, a day, and a year. You do not need to verify that the month, day, and year are sensible values. You may NOT assume that the month, day, and year are given as integers, and you must require the user to give you integers. Example ("> " is the prompt):

```
  > add Natalie Hershlag 6 9 1981 
    Added "Natalie Hershlag, 6/9/1981" to birthday book. 

    > add William Pitt 12 18 1963 
    Added "William Pitt, 12/18/1963" to birthday book. 

    > add John Depp 6 9 1963 
    Added "John Depp, 6/9/1963" to birthday book. 

    > add Bono 
    Error: unable to add birthday to book. Add requires 5 arguments.

    > add Paul Hewson May 10 1960
    Error: unable to add birthday to book. Please use integers for dates.
```

### 2. List all entries in the book.

Command syntax: list
Prints out a list of all birthday book entries, numbered, one per line. Example:

```
> list

1. Madonna Ciccone, 8/16/1958
2. Natalie Hershlag, 6/9/1981
3. William Pitt, 12/18/1963
4. John Depp, 6/9/1963
```

### 3. Delete an entry in the book by number.

Command syntax: delete number
You may NOT assume that the user will always give an integer as the number that they want to delete. After
checking to see that the entry number is valid, the program should verify that the user really wants to delete the
entry by asking for a "y" or a "n", which mean "yes" or "no" respectively. You should continue to prompt for a
"y" or a "n" until you get one or the other. Example:

```
> list
1. Madonna Ciccone, 8/16/1958
2. Natalie Hershlag, 6/9/1981
3. William Pitt, 12/18/1963
4. John Depp, 6/9/1963
> delete 3
Really delete William Pitt from the birthday book? (y/n) y
> list
1. Madonna Ciccone, 8/16/1958
2. Natalie Hershlag, 6/9/1981
3. John Depp, 6/9/1963
> delete 4
I'm sorry, but there is no such entry in the book.
> delete 1
Really delete Madonna Ciccone from the birthday book? (y/n) nada
Please enter "y" or "n". (y/n) n
> list
1. Madonna Ciccone, 8/16/1958
2. Natalie Hershlag, 6/9/1981
3. John Depp, 6/9/1963
```

How would I go about starting this question? I need to incorporate the use of classes as well? I don't need specific code, but rather a general point on how to start this.
Would I start by putting each function (add, list, delete) into a different class to deal with them and having a common array in the main class?

Comment: howdy!  SO isn't really for "how do I solve this homework question, generally", it is intended for questions of the form "i did all this work, but this one little specific thing doesn't work, I've tried X, Y, and Z, what am I missing?"

Comment: What have you done so far? S.O. isn't a place where others do homeworks for you, we can help, but you should show effort.

Comment: Thats the problem. I just need a place to start. Like a hint.
How to begin the problem.

Comment: At the very least you should have a BookEntry class with properties like Name and Birthday just to hold the data for the individual records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of helping, I'll give you a starting point:

```
Console.ReadLine <-- gives you inputs from what they typed in
```

You will need some classes, for example:

```
public class Person {
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
  public Date BirthDate;
}
```

Then you're going to want to have a main class that does some sort of printing with lines like

```
Console.WriteLine("Gimme stuffs");
```

and maybe even some

```
foreach(var p in People){
  Console.WriteLine("Found person {0} {1}, {2}",p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.BirthDate);
}
```

and somewhere in that main class you'll have something like

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
```

---

Validation:

I would make some sort of a thing like:

```
public static Person GetPerson(string str){
    var all = str.Split(' ');
    var p = new Person();
    p.FirstName = all[0];
    p.LastName = all[1];
    int month = (int)all[2];
    int day = (int)all[3];
    int year = (int)all[4];
    p.BirthDate = new Date(year,month,day);
    return p;
}
```

and for a fast validation:

```
if(str.Split(' ').Length != 5) //you don't have a valid input line
```

but then also

```
int testInt = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(str.Split(' ')[3], out testInt)) //you don't have a valid month
```

---

Now, that's a lot of help. Go forth and TRY FOR YOURSELF.

Comment: Thank you.
How would you store each individual person in an array?

Comment: And trust me, this isn't even very advanced. I would actually do it entirely differently but I'm not what appears to be a 1st year CS student ...